# passing an variable from controller to model with Mass Assignment in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mass-assignment

I am new in Laravel.

I am going to upload image in Laravel I use [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) and this is my **controller**:

```
public function store()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), City::$rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
        $image_temp=Input::file('image');
        $name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        if(Image::make($image_temp->getRealPath())->save('public/up/city/'.$name)){
            $image='public/up/city/'.$name;
        }
        City::create($data);
        return Redirect::route('siteadmin.cities.index');
    }
```

And this is my **model**:

```
class City extends \Eloquent {
   protected $primaryKey='city_id';
   protected $fillable = ['name', 'parent_id', 'english_name','population','phone_prefix','image'];
}
```

And this is my **route**:

```
Route::resource('cities', 'CitiesController');
```

everything is working well but I don't know how to send an variable as a special field to Mass Assignment.

I need **$image** variable to save in *cities* table **image** field

```
if(Image::make($image_temp->getRealPath())->save('public/up/city/'.$name)){
                $image='public/up/city/'.$name;
            }
```

But image in my database filled with temporary name of uploaded file:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the value in the `$data` array:

```
$data['image'] = 'public/up/city/'.$name;
```

If you do

```
$image = 'public/up/city/'.$name;
```

... you store the value in a local variable but nothing happens with it. The value in your DB comes from the "original" `$data`, the form data. It's the temporary path of the uploaded file. You need to change that in order for Laravel to fill the new value in the DB.

---

And here the (nearly) full code to avoid any confusion:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), City::$rules);
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
$image_temp=Input::file('image');
$name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
if(Image::make($image_temp->getRealPath())->save('public/up/city/'.$name)){
    $data['image'] = 'public/up/city/'.$name;
}
City::create($data);
return Redirect::route('siteadmin.cities.index');
```

Comment: He's already saving that as `$image` so how about just `$data['image'] = $image;`

Comment: Oh again you, Thanks a lot. can you please tell me why Laravel is assignment it automatically?

Comment: @user3158900 The `$image` variable is used nowhere else so I would eliminate it completely.

Comment: Because you told it to when you used `Input::all()` to get your data and then mass assigned that data without modifying it first.  All Laravel knows is the temp directory where the file was stored by PHP when it was uploaded.

Comment: @user3158900 can you please answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985327/laravel-controller-update-method-not-working