# Laravel Controller update method not working

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am new in Laravel.

I made  controller, Model and views by **way/generator** by composer `php artisan generate:scaffold cities` and Its index page (Create and store method) Working well but I don't know what is the problem with `update` method.

This is my CitiesController method(**Update**):

```
public function update($id)
{
    $city = City::findOrFail($id);

    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), City::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $city->update($data);
    return Redirect::route('admin.cities.index');
}
```

This is my model (**city**):

```
class City extends \Eloquent {
   protected $primaryKey='city_id';

    public static $rules = [
         'name'     => 'required',
         'image'     => 'mimes:jpeg',
         'parent_id' => 'required',
         'name'      => 'required',
         'english_name'=>'unique:cities,english_name|required'

    ];
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'parent_id', 'english_name','population','phone_prefix','image'];
}
```

And this is my view (**edit**):

```
<ul>
    {{ Form::model($city,array('route'=>array('admin.cities.update',$city->id),'method'=>'PUT','files'=>true)) }}
    <!--Here I included my form-->
    @include('admin.forms._partial.formcity')
    <li>
        {{ Form::submit('submit') }}
    </li>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</ul>
```

And this is my Route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin','before'=>'Auth'),function(){
    Route::resource('cities', 'CitiesController');
});
```

When I click on submit button Laravel throwout this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

***note***:My view works well. I think the problem is from controller method, and other methods of this controller like `create` and `store` works well too.

Comment: that problem is generated beacause you have a defective route declaration in your routes.php

Comment: please give us your routes.php

Comment: @ITroubs I added my route too

Comment: one route sais "admin.cities...." but the form has a route that points to "siteadmin.cities....." is that correct or should the form rather point to "admin.cities.update"?

Comment: @ITroubs Yes, I know that, This is now the problem and I edited now

Comment: how do the other routes you use for the store and so on look like?

Comment: On the command line under the laravel directory, try `php artisan routes` and make sure you are using the correct route name and there are no duplicate route names.

Comment: So, when you update, what does it show? is there a validation error. or try echo $id and Input::all() see if you are getting those values or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you have `protected $primaryKey='city_id';` but in your view you have:

```
{{ Form::model($city,array('route'=>array('admin.cities.update',$city->id),'method'=>'PUT','files'=>true)) }}
```

I mean `$city->id` should be `$city->city_id`